# Calling WebService protected by Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-identity-platform

I have deployed a web application to Azure App Services and set up the App Service Authentication to use Active Directory.

In the console application, I have the following code.

```
string baseUrl = "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/Admin/GetCustomers";
string sAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennant ID}“;
string sClient = “{“Client ID};
string sClientSecret = “{“ClientSecret};


IConfidentialClientApplication app;
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(sClient)
          .WithClientSecret(sClientSecret)
          .WithAuthority(new Uri(sAuthority))
          .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/Admin/.default" }; 
         
AuthenticationResult result = null;
result =  app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    JObject resultData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
    Console.WriteLine("Finished Loading Data!");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Error Happened");
}
```

Based on following your guide I have 2 Application Registered in ActiveDirectory

1. Server App has Exposed API
   https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/Admin/ with scope of GetCustomers
2. Web URI - https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/auth-response and https://testapp.azurewebsites.net

Client App has permission to this scope
As Admin I granted it and I created a ClinetSecret

What did I forget to do?
Steve

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because you're getting a token for the graph api scope:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
result =  app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

The token returned from that call would work if you were calling the graph api instead:

```
string baseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1/me"
```

But that's not what you're after. What you need to do is to create a scope which provides access to your API so that AAD can issue an appropriate token.

To do this, you'll want to 'Expose an API' in the Azure portal when managing the web app where your API is hosted. You can use a custom named scope which you create or `[app id uri]/.default` instead.

[Here is a walkthrough of the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)

[More detail on scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon#requesting-tokens)

Comment: Josh - I tried to follow the walkthrough and it still gives me 401.                               AD TestApp
   - Redirect URI’s

https://testing.azurewebsites.net
https://testing.azurewebsites.net/auth-response

Expose API
ApplicationID URI - https://testing.azurewebsites.net/Admin

Scope
https://testing.azurewebsites.net/Admin/GetCustomers


ClientApp
ClientSecret
Api Permissions
   - TestingApp GetCustomers                                                            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://testing.azurewebsites.net/admin/.default" };

Comment: Add your updated code to the original question and I'll see if I can spot the problem. Double check your scope name per this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#verify-the-exposed-scopes